# Java shoot towards mouse

Tags: java, mouse

I have a top down 2d game where you walk around shooting bad guys. I want to be able to shoot towards the mouse, no mater what direction it is but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Here is my `bullet` class:

```
public class bullet {

public double x, y,dy,dx,mx,my;
public int dir;

public Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);

public bullet(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x+10;
    this.y = y+10;
    this.mx = Comp.mx;
    this.my = Comp.my;
    r = new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
    if (x < mx+play.camx) {
        dx = 1;
    }
    if (x > mx+play.camx) {
        dx = -1;
    }
    if (y < my+play.camy) {
        dy = 1;
    }
    if (y > my+play.camy) {
        dy = -1;
    }
}

public void tick() {
    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;

    r = new Rectangle((int) x - play.camx, (int) y - play.camy, 5, 5);
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect((int) x - play.camx, (int) y - play.camy, 5, 5);
}
}
```

Comment: So you have two points (start//end), you need to calculate the angel between them

Comment: http://wikicode.wikidot.com/get-angle-of-line-between-two-points

Comment: the how do I apply it?

Answer (score 2):

Basicially, you need calculate the angel between the start point and end point, something like...

```
angle = -Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(startX - endX, startY - endY)) + 180;
```

As an example:

- [Rotating a triangle around a point java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260445/rotating-a-triangle-around-a-point-java/27260788#27260788)
- [Java make a directed line and make it move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607427/java-make-a-directed-line-and-make-it-move/15607737#15607737)
- [mouse motion listener only in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129281/mouse-motion-listener-only-in-one-direction/20131064#20131064)
- [Java: Move image towards mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784303/java-move-image-towards-mouse-position/26791886#26791886)

To track the mouse, use a `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListerner`

Take a look at:

- [How to write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [How to write a MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getPosition() ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation%28%29)  It will return a point object. 
Use a timer and on every timer event you'll move your bullet a specific length (which you would want it to move) towards the mouse position provided by aforementioned method. 
You could do it like reducing difference of x- and y- Variables of mouse position and bullet position.

Comment: I am trying to do this without using added libraries

Comment: Have you considered attaching a mouselistener to the panel or something where you're drawing in?

Comment: yes I have no problem getting the cords of mouse x and mouse y I just cant do the angle and direction of the bullet

Comment: Or use a MouseMotionListener and get the call backs for free

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem