# How do I get my mouse coordinates relative to the window rather than the screen?

Tags: java, jframe, mouse, mouselistener

I am trying to get the coordinates of my mouse relative to the window.
I understand that I need to reference the JFrame or something but cannot for the life of me figure out how, my class provided me with this beginner code and I have built it up from there.

```
public class TheGame extends JFrame 
{
public static final int WIDTH = 785;
public static final int HEIGHT = 670;
public static int width;
public static int height;
public static int borderX;
public static int borderY;

public TheGame()
{
    super("PLATFORMGAME");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    PlatformGame game = new PlatformGame();

    ((Component)game).setFocusable(true);
    getContentPane().add(game);



    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    TheGame run = new TheGame();
}
}
```

Here is my mouse listener class:

```
public class mouse extends JFrame {

static Point p;
BufferedImage sprite;

public mouse() {
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
try {
    sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("mouse_pointer.png")) ;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}

}

public Point getlocation() {
 return p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
}

public static double getNorP(double uno, double dos) {
    if ((uno - dos) > 0) {return -1;}
    else {return 1;}

}
public static double getX(Char c) {
    return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x ;
    //return  MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x -       ReferenceJFrame.getLocationOnScreen().x;

}
public static double getY(Char c) {
    return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y -29;
    //return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - ReferenceJFrame.getLocationOnScreen().y;
}
public static double getXD(Char c) {
return Math.abs(c.rX-(double)getX(c));
}
public static double getYD(Char c) {
return Math.abs(c.rY-(double)getY(c));
}
    //  public static float getAngle(Point target,int x,int y) {
    //    return (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(getX()-x, getY()-y));
}
public static double getXP(Char c) {
    return (getXD(c))/(getXD(c)+getYD(c)) * getNorP(c.rX,getX(c));
}
public static double getYP(Char c) {
    return (getYD(c))/(getXD(c)+getYD(c)) * getNorP(c.rY,getY(c));
}

public void draw(Graphics window, Char c) {

    window.drawImage(sprite,(int) getX(c)-16,(int) getY(c)-8, 16, 16, null);

}

}
```

This returns the coordinates of the mouse relative to the screen but not to the window. I understand a fair amount of java except for JFrame type stuff.

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). Add the `MouseListener` to `PlatformGame` and this will trigger mouse events which are within the components coordinate space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't use `MouseInfo`, this isn't really your best choice for getting the mouse location, instead, start by adding a `MouseListener` to your `PlatformGame`, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

This will, when the mouse listener is called, pass a `MouseEvent` which will be within the coordinate space of the component the `MouseListener` is registered to, so, no need to do any conversions whatsoever!

Now, if for some bizarre reason, you still want to convert from the `PlatformGame` coordinate space to the frame's, you could use something as simple as...

```
evt = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(evt.getComponent(), evt, SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(evt.getComponent()));
```

where `evt` is the `MouseEvent`

Comment: thank you so much this is a much simpler way to make it work!

Comment: is it possible for me to use e.getX() from the mouse listener without having an event (ex: click), i have something that follows uses the mouse coordinates to shoot an arrow in that direction. what i was using before is slightly off. I just need to access mouse x and y at anytime

Comment: Maybe a `MouseMotionListener`?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784303/java-move-image-towards-mouse-position/26791886#26791886) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129281/mouse-motion-listener-only-in-one-direction/20131064#20131064) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607427/java-make-a-directed-line-and-make-it-move/15607737#15607737) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260445/rotating-a-triangle-around-a-point-java/27260788#27260788)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JFrame`'s method `getLocation()` that returns a `Point` object. Then use something like:

```
mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - frame.getLocation().x;
mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - frame.getLocation().y;
```

In your case the getMouseLocation() method would look like this:

```
public Point getMouseLocation(){
    int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - run.getLocation().x;
    int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - run.getLocation().y;
    return new Point(x,y);
}
```

Comment: That would work, but what is the name of my frame? i.e how do i reference it?

Comment: probably `this` since your class `extends JFrame`

Comment: @squirt706 Actually you would want to reference `run` if that is the frame you are comparing against.

Comment: ok that makes sense can you provide me with a code sample of how to reference it? @Jonah_Haney and thanks for the help